# Find all transitive dependencies of Java Class including implementation classes used only via their interfaces

Tags: java, dependencies, static-code-analysis, jdeps

My aim is to list down all the transitive dependencies of the public API classes of my project and use that to focus testing effort in case of any code changes made to those dependencies.

For example:

```
class MyApi {
    MyDao md;
    public void methodA() {
        //do something with md;
    }
}

interface MyDao { }

class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao { }
```

So if I know that MyDaoImpl has been modified (say from the commit history) and I know MyApi.methodA uses MyDaoImpl, then my testing should focus on checking it. I need a list of dependencies of MyApi.methodA() including both MyDao and MyDaoImpl.

I've tried two tools so far - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html and http://depfind.sourceforge.net/ - they are promising but don't seem to completely solve the problem. For both tools it seems that if a class depends upon an interface, there is no built in way to include the implementations of that interface as transitive dependencies.

Is there a way to pull this information from any tools without heavy customization?

Comment: you should add `md = new MyDaoImpl()` in your method. Otherwise `MyDaoImpl` has no connection to your appli.

Comment: The actual code uses spring for injecting the implementation classes, so there really is no new MyDaoImpl(). I'm looking for some way to pull in all implementations of the interfaces that MyApi is using even if there's no  created directly in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) for your need.
Right clicking a method anywhere in the UI, and selecting the menu: *Select Method... > ...that are using me (directly or indirectly)* leads to a code query like:

```
from m in Methods 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("myNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod()")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }
```

The problem is that such query gives indirect usage, but doesn't look for calls that occurs **via an interface** (or an overridden method declared in a base class).

Hopefully what you are asking for can be obtained with this query:

```
// Retrieve the target method by name
let methodTarget = Methods.WithFullName(""myNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod()"").Single()

// Build a ICodeMetric<IMethod,ushort> representing the depth of indirect
// call of the target method.
let indirectCallDepth = 
   methodTarget.ToEnumerable()
   .FillIterative(
       methods => methods.SelectMany(
          m => m.MethodsCallingMe.Union(m.OverriddensBase)))

from m in indirectCallDepth.DefinitionDomain
select new { m, callDepth = indirectCallDepth[m]  }
```

The two corner stones of this query are:

- The call to FillIterative() to select recursively the indirect call.
- The call to the property IMethod.OverriddensBase, as its name suggests. For a method **M** this returns the enumerable of all method declared in a base class or an interface, overriden by **M**.

Comment: Thanks James, JArchitect query seems to work as I expected.